# SPOJ RPLD - What's wrong with my solution

Tags: c++, stl

Here's my code that finds if a pair (id,c) exists already. I use a multimap to store the (id,c) pair values. I keep getting wrong answer to this code. Where am I going wrong?
Problem Link - http://www.spoj.com/problems/RPLD/
I get correct answer to the test case given in the problem. But getting WA after submission.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int t,i=1;
  cin >> t;
  while(t--){
      int n , r, f;
      cin >> n >> r;
      multimap <long int ,long int> s;
      pair <long int,long int> p;
      f= 0;
      while(r > 0){
          long int id,c,idx =0;          
          cin >> id >> c;
          if(f == 0){
          p = make_pair(id,c);
          for(multimap<long int,long int>::iterator it = s.find(id); it != s.end(); it++){
              ++idx;
              if(it->second == c)
                  f=1;               
          }
          if(idx == 0)
                s.insert(p);
          idx = 0;          
          }
          --r;
      }      
      if(f==0)
        cout << "Scenario #"<<i<<": possible"<<endl;
      else
        cout << "Scenario #"<<i<<": impossible"<<endl;
     ++i;     
      s.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: Please check this problem link for expected input and output http://www.spoj.com/problems/RPLD/

Comment: There's no guarantee regarding which element `find` returns if a key occurs more than once in a `multimap`. I would recommend `std::map<long int, std::vector<long int>>` instead of the `multimap`.

Comment: I tried multimap.equal_range() to get all the values for a key. Still gives WA.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @molbdnilo . I tried map<long int, set<long int>> and it works. Not sure why multimap.equal_range() didn't work though.